# How to discard mails sent from a specific local user to external addresses?

Tags: postfix

How can I configure Postfix to silently drop / discard mails that were sent from one of my users to an external address?

I'm already able to discard all mails to external addresses using the following transport_maps

```
example.com      :
*          discard:
```

However I want to apply this rule to one user within my Postfix server only.

Also mails addressed to external and local addresses should get deliverd to the local users only.

#### Why do I need this?

The company I work at thinks that an intern should not sent mails directly to the customer. So the intern would send a mail using the customers address for `to` and adding his supervisor into the `cc`. Then Postfix shoud only deliver the mail to the supervisor so that he can check and sent the mail to the customer without searching for the customers address.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To do what OP need, we need a check at transport level, which turn out to be simple.

1. Add following line to **/etc/postfix/main.cf**

   ```
   sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_transport_maps
   ```
2. Create **/etc/postfix/sender_transport_maps** as follow

   ```
   user@local.domain   discard
   ```
3. Create postfix map file and restart postfix

   ```
   cd /etc/postfix
   postmap sender_transport_maps
   service postfix restart
   ```

This method works because postfix only use transport map for out-bound mail. In this case, instead of using a normal smtp service (smtp:), we use postfix DISCARD service.

Comment: This just discards all mails from that sender - but I want to discard *external* mails only (mails not ending with @example.com)

Comment: So you want a specific user's email to a specific address be discarded?

Comment: Almost. I want a specific users's mails to be send to the local addresses only - external mails from this user should be discarded silently.

Comment: ok, i have to revise the answer later. I am outside now and this is soemthing you don't keep in your head, lol.

Comment: no problem - and thank you for helping me!

Comment: @Martin Updated

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't allow the user to send mails that contain external (to:) and local (cc:) addresses because it does reject and not discard the mail.

Comment: hmm, ok, will revise.

Comment: I even tried to use `!/example.com/i   DISCARD` as local_domains but this will discard the entire mail - also for local users

Comment: @Martin that will not work as it is doing the check as email arrive. We need a check when email send out. That is what I am looking for now.

Comment: @Martin Updated and should meet exactly what you need.

Comment: it works - you saved me ... thank you so much for not giving me up after the first try!

Comment: I follow your method by setting `sender_dependent_default_transport_maps`, and it works. However, if someone pretends to be a powerful user by setting "Mail from address", he can still send mail outside.

Comment: If I want to read the discard email, is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

The sender_dependent_default_transport_maps didn't work at all for me. Even with smtpd -vv in master.cf to increase debug didn't help let me know why it didn't work (possibly an old postfix version).

Instead I used

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access  pcre:/etc/postfix/sender_domains, discard
```

with the sender_domains file containing

```
/user_to_be_blocked@domain.com/  DISCARD
/@domain.com/ OK
```

for eg, then restart postfix (pcre files do not need to be/can't be postmap'd)